# Should we merge [serializer] and [serialization] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Any time [serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serializer) could apply, [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serialization) would be a better target.

"Serializer" would only make sense if it referred to a specific serialization component or library, but as a generic concept it's too ambiguous and is many times used to refer to libraries like the Django or Symfony serializers.

I think that these two should be merged and [serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serializer) (545) should be made a synonym for [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serialization) (27,905).

Comment: Yeah, [tag:serializer] looks like it is being used for different kind of serialization libraries, and can probably be merged with [tag:serialization].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the top rated questions in [serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serializer), and most of them were about the concept of serialization. A lot of the questions seem to be about specific serializer libraries, which again are all about serialization. And finally, if we remove the questions related to [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django), the top related tags for both the tags are the same. I went ahead and added it as a synonym:

[serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serializer) (× 650) → [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serialization) (× 29113)

I'll merge them after a few days, just in case there are any issues with the synonym. For now, [serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serializer) joins the list of [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serialization) synonyms, which includes [serialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serialisation), [serialze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serialze), [serializing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serializing), [serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serialized), [unserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unserialize), [deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deserialize) and [serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/serialize)